# In postman, how to save all open tabs, which are having unsaved changes, with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: postman

How to save all currently open tabs having unsaved changes in them with a single shortcut key or key combination?
In certain interfaces, `CTRL`+`Shift`+`s` does the work and in some others, it can be configured. Is there such an option in postman?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to `right-click` on any tab and choose `close other tabs` then it will automatically ask you if you want to save or not ( not sure if it will ask you for every tab or if it is once for all.

Answer (score 1):

There's no a "Save All" action or something like that in Postman. Check this : https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4671

Comment: What is the gist of the link, in case it is deleted?